# Can't generate hoogle data because wget certificate expired?

Tags: haskell, hoogle

I'm trying to run 'hoogle data', and I get this as the output :

```
Downloading downloads/base.txt
# base.txt (for downloads/base.txt)
ERROR: cannot verify www.haskell.org's certificate, issued by '/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2':
  Issued certificate has expired.
To connect to www.haskell.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
hoogle: Error when running Shake build system:
* default.hoo
* platform.hoo
* mtl.hoo
* base.txt
* downloads/base.txt.cache
* downloads/base.txt
Development.Shake.command, system command failed
Command: wget -nv http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/base.txt --output-document=downloads/base.txt
Exit code: 5
Stderr:
ERROR: cannot verify www.haskell.org's certificate, issued by '/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2':
  Issued certificate has expired.
To connect to www.haskell.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I'm not sure what to do, last time I ran hoogle data it just worked and generated everything, but I can't figure out how to get around this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get around this problem, try creating a wrapper for `wget`:

I'll assume your installed `wget` is located at /usr/bin/wget

Save this file as `wget` somewhere in your `$PATH` and make sure it is executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate "$@"
```

Now retry your hoogle command.

Comment: Wouldn't hoogle still use the original wget? Why would it prefer to use the wrapper?

Comment: hoogle uses the PATH to find wget. If a PATH search finds your version first it will use that. So place the wrapper in a directory that appears before `/usr/bin` in your PATH.